# Sign In form disappeared? Meteor tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, forms, meteor

I'm using meteor with [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-messaging-for-meteor-with-meteor-streams--net-33409)
and there is supposed to be a sign up form at the top left of the chat box. There is not for some reason. All of my code is the same as the tutorial's (or very similar) but for some reason it just isn't showing up. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!-- Home Template -->
    <template name="home">
                <div id="box">
          {{> mainBox}}
        </div>
    </template>

<!-- Main Chat Window -->
    <template name='mainBox'>
      <div class='container'>
        <!-- shows login buttons -->
        {{loginButtons}}
        {{> chatBox}}
      </div>
    </template>

<!-- Chat Box with chat messages and the input box -->
    <template name='chatBox'>
      <div id='messages'>
        {{#each messages}}
          {{>chatMessage}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
      <textarea id='chat-message'></textarea><br>
      <button class='btn' id='send'>Send</button>
    </template>

    <!-- Template for the individual chat message -->
    <template name='chatMessage'>
      <div>
        <b>{{user}}:</b> {{message}}
      </div>
    </template>
```

Javascript:

```
// render all of our messages in the ui
Template.chatBox.helpers({
  "messages": function() {
    return chatCollection.find();
  }
});

// get the value for handlerbar helper user
Template.chatMessage.helpers({
  "user": function() {
    if(this.userId == 'me') {
      return this.userId;
    } else if(this.userId) {
      getUsername(this.userId);
      return Session.get('user-' + this.userId);
    } else {
      return 'anonymous-' + this.subscriptionId;
    }
  }
});

// when Send Chat clicked at the message to the collection
Template.chatBox.events({
 "click #send": function() {
  $('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
    var message = $('#chat-message').val();
    chatCollection.insert({
      userId: 'me',
      message: message
    });
    $('#chat-message').val('');

    //add the message to the stream
    chatStream.emit('chat', message);
  },

  "keypress #chat-message": function(e) { 
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('#messages').animate({"scrollTop": $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}, "fast");
      console.log("you pressed enter");
      e.preventDefault();
      //repeat function from #send click event here
      var message = $('#chat-message').val();
    chatCollection.insert({
      userId: 'me',
      message: message
    });
    $('#chat-message').val('');

    //add the message to the stream
    chatStream.emit('chat', message);
    }
  }
});

chatStream.on('chat', function(message) {
  chatCollection.insert({
    userId: this.userId,
    subscriptionId: this.subscriptionId,
    message: message
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 800px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

#box {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

#chat-message {
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    border-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 721px;
    min-width: 721px;
    max-height: 300px;
}

#messages {
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #373737;
    min-width: 725px;
    max-width: 725px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-indent: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    word-spacing: 0.1em;
}

#send {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3EAC3E;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', Arial;
    margin-left: 609px;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you added the `accounts-ui` package to your project: `mrt add accounts-ui`?

Comment: Oops I forgot to add that. I added it and now it says "no login services configured". What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have gone through each and every one of these steps before coding:

```
$ meteor create awesome-chat-app
$ cd awesome-chat-app
$ meteor remove insecure autopublish
$ meteor add bootstrap accounts-password accounts-ui
$ mrt add streams
$ rm awesome-chat-app.* //remove files added automatically
```

If you have not, you can now try:

```
$ meteor remove insecure autopublish
$ meteor add bootstrap accounts-password accounts-ui
$ mrt add streams
```

To make sure you have everything properly installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to Meteor 0.8.0 you need to to:

**{{> loginButtons}} instead of {{loginButtons}}**

Else your app will not load (like the parties examples)