# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or No login services configured

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to make a sample app with meteor together with bootstrap. 
Unfortunately I get either Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' after running 'meteor remove insecure autopublish' command in order to work with accounts-ui package - following post [Sign In form disappeared? Meteor tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521850/sign-in-form-disappeared-meteor-tutorial).

It seems I get either 'No login services configured' message if autopublish+insecure are installed or 'Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined' in case bootstrap is installed.

Needless to say each solution works separately.

How do I overcome this weird mutex?

Thanks in advance,
Igor